# tuple to string formatting

Tags: python, tuples

After a certain calculation i am getting an output like:

```
('      ','donor','       ','distance')  

('      ','ARG','A','43','  ','3.55')  
('      ','SOD','B',93', '  ','4.775')  
('      ','URX','C',33', '   ','3.55')
```

while i was intending to get like:

```
  donor            distance
    ARG A 43         3.55
    SOD B 93         4.77
    URX C 33         3.55
```

the thing what i am getting is a tuple, but i am very confused on how to make this tuple into a well formatted look as per my desire.
Please give some idea...
thank you.

Comment: I noticed with the value "4.775" that you wanted it to print "4.77", which involves truncation.  Is this correct or did you just forget the "5"?

Comment: ya, it is correct. I agree with your view.. @icodez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data looks like this

```
data = [
    ('      ', 'donor', '       ', 'distance'),
    ('      ', 'ARG', 'A', '43', '       ', '3.55'),
    ('      ', 'SOD', 'B', '93', '       ', '4.775'),
    ('      ', 'URX', 'C', '33', '       ', '3.55')
]
```

Then you can just

```
print '\n'.join(map(' '.join, data))
```

Comment: Now I'll help you.  Put this `map(' '.join, data)` in order to print it like the OP wants.

Comment: :) Looks like you had that coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join()` on each tuple:

```
' '.join(your_tuple)
```

before printing.

Comment: tried that... like ' '.join(str(my_tuple).strip('()').. not being able to get the required formatting..

Comment: I never said you should use `str()` on the tuple. I told you to use `''.join(my_tuple)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for-loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
lis = [
    ('     ','donor','    ','distance'),
    ('      ','ARG','A','43','  ','3.55'),
    ('      ','SOD','B','93', '  ','4.775'),
    ('      ','URX','C','33', '  ','3.55')
]

for item in lis:
    print " ".join(item)
```

Output:

```
 donor      distance
   ARG A 43    3.55
   SOD B 93    4.775
   URX C 33    3.55
```

Comment: why can't you just do `" ".join(item)` directly?

Comment: @Downvoter - Could you please give a reason you downvoted?  I take the quality of my work very seriously.  Hence, if you have found something that you believe is a problem, please let me know so that I can either fix it or explain better.

Comment: I don't think @Downvoter would get a notification about your message, or would they? FWIW wasn't me :)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to use [format strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).  For example, assuming that you are *not* storing padding strings in your items:

```
print "{0} {1} {2}   {3:>10.2f}".format(*item)
```

You can specify the exact format (including width and alignment) of each field of the record in the format string.  In this example, the fourth string is right-aligned to fit into 10 characters, with 2 digits displayed to the right of the decimal point.

Example using your data:

```
>>> x = (('      ','ARG','A','43','  ','3.55'),('      ','SOD','B','93', '  ','4.775'),('      ','URX','C','33', '   ','3.55'))
>>> f = "{0:3s}{1:1s}{2:2s} {3:>10.3f}"
>>> for item in x: print f.format(item[1], item[2], item[3], float(item[5]))
...
ARGA43      3.550
SODB93      4.775
URXC33      3.550
```

Comment: I ran into this mistake too at first. ;)  The OP didn't want the data like "ARGA43" but "ARG A 43".  Check his post.

Comment: @iCodez The example I gave is just that, an example. This can be fixed by adding two spaces in the format string. My answer was to direct the OP to format strings in the first place, as they are likely to be the most useful way to approach this problem.